# how do i stop or remove an addEventListener in flash cs6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi guys I need some help, I'm a total AS3 novice.
I have a flash project with 4 scenes in a loop, and the last scene has a snowflake falling script applied.

I found this snow script to use in my project. Works great but I have no idea of how to limit the animation only to the particular scene it starts on. the scenes keep looping and the snow doesn't stop.

Scene it starts on goes for 300 frames, if that help at all.

Here is the code:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, snow);
function snow(event: Event): void {
    var scale: Number = Math.random() * 0.6;
    var _sf: snowflake = new snowflake();
    _sf.x = Math.random() * 640;
    _sf.scaleX = scale;
    _sf.scaleY = scale;
    var speed: Number = Math.random() * 2;
    var RA: Array = new Array(-1, 1);
    var lf: int = RA[Math.round(Math.random())];
    stage.addChild(_sf);
    _sf.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, snowfall);
    function snowfall(event: Event): void {
        _sf.y += speed;
        _sf.rotation += Math.random() * 20;
        _sf.x += (Math.random() * 2) * lf;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks Rick

Comment: Do NOT use inner functions for addEventListener. You won't be able to remove it because it will not be in the visible scope (its scope is the snow function only).

Comment: Hi Fygo, as I didn't write the code, can you suggest a way to fix this so the falling snow effect can be stopped at the end of the scene, and the scenes can continue to loop. thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I end up finding a better script for the snow animation, that plays for the duration of the scene.

here it is - for reference.

```
import flash.events.Event;

var snowflakes:Array = new Array();
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
function loop(e:Event) {
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        var scale: Number = Math.random() * 0.6;
        var s = new flake();
        s.x=Math.random()*550;
        s.scaleX = scale;
        s.scaleY = scale;
        s.y=-10;
        s.speedY=1+Math.random()*2;
        s.speedX=2-Math.random()*3;
        addChild(s);
        snowflakes.push(s);
    }
    for (i=snowflakes.length-1; i>0; i--) {
        snowflakes[i].y+=snowflakes[i].speedY;
        snowflakes[i].x+=snowflakes[i].speedX;
        if (snowflakes[i].y>600) {
            removeChild(snowflakes[i]);
            snowflakes.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I then added this on the last frame of the scene, and it worked.

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
```

Answer (score 0):

removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, snow);

Answer (score -1):

Something like that:

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, snowfall);
```

Comment: As Fygo commented the line of code you posted simply cannot work. Voted down for giving an answer that cannot work.

Comment: I had tried that and as Fygo suggested, it didn't work.

Comment: @L6go1as... that code could work if placed in correct position (ie: not running within another function to handle yet another separate function etc). You could lose the downvotes by fixing the asker's shown code then posting it here as an answer. But that's for future questions...